# Adding result of column expression as new column on table variable creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm sure this is really easy but I can't think of a solution and can't seem to find any documentation that answers my exact question.

While inserting values into a table variable how do I set the value of a field to be the result of an expression from another field in the same table?

For example:

```
declare @tableVar table(
    [col1] int,
    [col2] dec(18,2),
    [col3] dec(18,2)
)
insert into @tableVar
values (100,.03,[col1] * [col2])

select *
from @tableVar
```

Would ideally return:

```
col1 col2 col3
100  0.03 3.00
```

But I get this error instead:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'col1'.

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Invalid column name 'col2'.
```

I understand why I get the error I just can't seem to come up with a solution.

Any hints?

Comment: why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: @TabAlleman I think the reasons for wanting to do something like this are more apparent than the reasons not to.. care to explain why this is a bad approach?

Comment: Because if the values of col1 and col2 are known, you can simply use those values to write the equation for col3 instead of column names.   In other words, `100.0*.03` instead of `[col1]*[col2]`   Why would you ever need to use the column names instead of the values when the values are known?

Comment: @TabAlleman I see your point if my table was going to be as simple as my example in my question. However, the example is just a subset of a much more complex table. There is going to be more than just 1 line in this table variable and many calculated fields. e.g, If there are 20 rows of data and 10 columns with 8 being calculated I only want to maintain 40 pieces (20 rows 2 columns) of static data as opposed to 200 (20 rows 10 columns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
insert into @tableVar (col1, col2, col3)
    select col1, col2, col1 * col2
    from (values (100, 0.03)) v(col1, col2);
```

Or, better yet, use a computed column:

```
declare @tableVar table (
    col1 int,
    col2 dec(18, 2),
    col3 as ( convert(dec(18, 2), col1 * col2) )
);

insert into @tableVar (col1, col2)
    values (100, 0.03);
```

Note that both these examples explicitly list the columns being inserted.  That is considered a best-practice.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply! I like the computed column approach. For future reference, if anybody stumbles upon this solution, you are missing a closing parenthesis on the col3 definition. Other than that, it works perfectly! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need `values` construct :

```
insert into @tableVar (col1, col2, col3)
   select col1, col2, col1 * col2
   from (values (100, .03) 
        ) t(col1, col2);
```